# Troubleshooting QuickBooks Web Connector issue

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Try to troubleshooting QuickBook's Web Connector by following helping URL: [Click Me](https://test.developer.intuit.com/QBWC/TroubleshootQBWC/index.aspx). When I try to Add an application into Web connector getting following error: "QBWC1048: QuickBooks Web Connector could not verify the web application server certificate. QBWC1051: The new application was not added"[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QuickBook throws the 1048 error because it is unable to complete a GET request at the AppURL that specified QBFS.qwc file. This is because test.developer.intuit.com restricts GET requests via the SOAP API.

To get around this, include a  parameter in the .qwc file, and set it to the same value as your AppURL without the URL path.
For example, if your AppURL is https://mycompany.cs1.force.com/services/Soap/class/myApiClass, then set CertURL to https://mycompany.cs1.force.com.

This is the solution suggested by the QBWC log file, and it worked for me.

[Reference URL](https://community.intuit.com/questions/1140861-getting-error-qbwc1048-in-quickbooks-web-connector)

Comment: I was able to add a `GET` method with the same URL that my SOAP method (which uses `POST`) was listening to.  This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found I had this problem because my software was trying to load the file

http://developer.intuit.com/uploadedFiles/Support/QBWebConnectorSvc.wsdl

which no longer exists. :(

So I got a WSDL from

https://test.developer.intuit.com/QBWC/TroubleshootWebServiceFS/Service.asmx?wsdl

and put it in my Site's root directory, then changed my code to point there, and it worked.